# ifttt webhook returns 403 (it works with curl)

Tags: github, github-actions, ifttt

I want to automatize a task, and the last step is to trigger a webhook on github. I am using ifttt "Make a web request"

This request works with curl

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.github.com/repos/wiso/TemperaturaUfficio/dispatches?event_type=webhook' \
--header 'Accept: application/vnd.github+json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "event_type": "test_webhook"
}'
```

I am trying to do the same with ifttt:

[image]

I get:

```
Your server returned a 403. Unable to make web request to https://api.github.com/repos/wiso/TemperaturaUfficio/dispatches?event_type=webhook
```

Comment: Are you triggering a workflow_dispatch or a repository_dispatch? For the first I would expect the ID of the workflow to be in the call url somewhere?

Comment: I am running a repository_dispatch. By the way, with curl it works

Comment: Are you using the GITHUB_TOKEN in the workflow? They changed the default scope it has recently, and it now only has ‘read’ rights. For the repo dispatch event you need ‘write’ as well. In that case, use the ‘permissions’ keyword to set it to ‘write’.

Comment: @RobBos but why it works with curl?

Comment: The GITHUB_TOKEN is only present in a workflow job, so you are using a different token in the curl command.

Comment: @RobBos, sorry, I don't undestand. The two requests are identical. The tokens which I have obfuscated are identical. I expect IFTTT do run exactly the same request as in curl, since the parameters are the same.